# Table Attribute defined in Table Entity

Tags: c#

I have a table entity here:

```
[Table("Table")]
public class Table
{
    public long A{ get; set; }
    public long B{ get; set; }

    public Table() 
    { 

    }

    public Table(long a, string b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;   
    }
}
```

Does any one could explain this part of code for me?

```
public Table() 
{ 

}

public Table(long a, string b)
{
    A = a;
    B = b;          
}
```

What is this part doing, a self-defined method? Why there is no any keyword after `public`? for example `public void Table(){}` something like this? And what is the next part doing?

Comment: It is the constructor and an overload of the constructor. Method gets called when a Table object gets created. Try typing `var table = new Table();` in your code. You will notice that you have two options, one without parameters and one with two parameters (long a and string b). Removing and re-adding the opening parenthesis on this code, would make visual studio show the available overloads. You can recognize that the methods are constructors, since they are both named after the class.

Comment: Note that the code you provided won't compile, is `b` a string or long value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ace5hbzh.aspx). The first one is parameterless and is called when you instantiate the class using no parameters like:

```
Table table = new Table();
```

Note that the parameterless constructor is usually needed for things like serialisation.

The second one takes in two `long` values as parameters and uses them to initialise the two public properties. It is used when instantiating the class like:

```
Table table = new Table(1, 1);
```

Here I have also assumed in the question you have made a typo and the constructor is actually defined as:

```
public Table(long a, long b) { /*...*/ }
```

This is because the public property is of type long, not string, and the constructor is setting `B` to the value of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is been overloaded in order to initialize as

```
Table table = Table(121, "My Table");
```

or

```
Table table = Table();
```

Sometimes an empty constructor is needed for external galleries, or for code maintainability (code-cleanness).

Answer (score 1):

```
// This is a "default" constructor
public Table() 
{ 

}

// This is an overloaded constructor 
// allowing the consumer to pass two variables in 
// that get set to the class properties A and B
public Table(long a, string b)
{
    A = a;
    B = b;          
}
```

There is no keyword after "public" because that's the way constructor syntax is defined.

For more information read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx